# Can I use Word 2003 component for converting .doc file to .pdf by using C#?

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I'm making a small application to verify whether Word 2003 documents can be converted into PDF format using C#, and I'm using the [`ExportAsFixedFormat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method.  It works in Word 2010.  Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb256835%28v=office.12%29.aspx), the `ExportToFixedFormat` method was added in Word 2007.  So I'm betting, no, you can't export a Word 2003 document.

One thing you could try is the [`Convert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb243727%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method, which in theory should allow you to convert the 2003 file to 2007 format, then export it to PDF.

Answer (score 1):

It will not work on 2003, as fas as I know, this Option was first introduced in Word 2007.

What you can always try: Install a pdf printer and use c# to "print" this document to this "printer".